Butterworth Filter for SMPS
If the performance of a Butterworth filter is dependent on the load impedance how do high voltage high power 1kW+ SMPSs manage to achieve smooth output ~100mV peak to peak across wide ranges of load impedances?
I assume they can't be utilizing active filters since there are hardly any opamps available for power levels that high.
UPDATE
There appears to be some confusion so to clarify things I am referring to the phenomenon which can be observed in the following simulation:

Butterworth filter with cutoff frequency of 1kHz was designed for 100kHz 50% duty cycle PWM signal and 50 ohm load. We can see its satisfying smooth output in green. Increasing the load to 500 ohms resulted in the messy blue output despite the fact that a cutoff frequency of 1kHz is much less than the switching frequency of 100kHz which according to John D's comment should've ensured smooth output even with higher load.
Now if we just replace the last capacitor with a big electrolytic one with ESR of 1 ohm as per Tim Williams's answer, then we get even weirder output shown in red.

The switching frequency is usually far above the cutoff frequency, so the magnitude of the ripple is small.  It will vary somewhat with load but the filter is designed to meet the system specs over the load conditions.

The edits substantially change the question; please revert them.  You are encouraged to ask further questions as new posts, however.

@TimWilliams No they don't? The question is literally about maintaining smooth output using a butterworth filter across variant loads and the edits show and discuss butterworth filter not handling different loads.

Filter prototypes aren't very important for SMPS and EMI use.  Generally we choose a cutoff frequency well below frequencies of interest in the system: switching frequency, or even control loop cutoff frequency (which is most often the case for voltage-mode controls).  Thus, pass/stop band ripples, or peaks or slow roll-offs due to mismatch, are significantly less important than the overall asymptote of the filter, and we might be more concerned about its losses at low frequencies (DC, or for class D amplifiers, the output signal bandwidth).
Note that the impedance is not well defined.  The output of a buck converter, at the switch itself, can have very low impedance: either RDS(on) of the pull-up transistor, or that of the pull-down switch (synchronous transistor or diode incremental resistance).  The average impedance can also be arbitrarily high, when DCM occurs (both switches are on only part of a cycle, or briefly between cycle skips, and open-circuit the remaining time).
Canonically, a voltage buck converter has a filter inductor and capacitor, forming a low-pass LC filter, where the L value is designed with priority towards switching behavior -- current slope and ripple -- rather than for filtering characteristics as such (Fc, Zo, etc.).
This is all to say, filter design is poorly defined under these circumstances, and we need to consider other aspects of the system instead.  We're certainly not going to have a Butterworth prototype in a real system, except perhaps under very limited operating conditions (given supply voltage, load current, etc.).
In general, since the inverter/switch output can be a near short circuit, we must consider a singly-terminated filter prototype.  That is, there is a short at one port, a series inductor (this is stipulated by the type being low-pass, and the port being shorted -- a shunt element first would do nothing!), alternating C and L inbetween, and finally the other port terminated into R = Zo.
How should we choose Zo?  The impedance of a filter is meaningful in terms of transient response: consider a step change in load current ΔI.  The corresponding peak change in voltage (during the filter's transient response) is ΔV = Zo ΔI, or thereabouts.  If we require output impedance (i.e., regulation in response to load change) to be lower than some margin, we can choose Zo accordingly.
Since the load will not, in general, provide termination, and the filter is one-side-shorted anyway, we must provide termination.  The easiest way to do this is to introduce significant AC losses in at least one reactive component in the filter.  Usually, we choose an overly-large capacitor at the output, with well-defined resistance.  The most common choice of component to provide this, is an electrolytic capacitor: large capacities are cheap and common, and ESR can be chosen to provide adequate damping.
The filter may also be well-damped due to response of the control circuit.  Effectively, the inverter output impedance is not actually zero, but it responds dynamically to inverter current (e.g. peak current mode control with slope compensation), or the control loop acts to regulate output voltage (or other variables along the way), and acting to dampen the filter without output termination (or with less required).
Control response, of course, does not apply to filters outside the loop -- usually the case for input filtering, where indeed the impedance may have a negative-resistance characteristic (an SMPS with load has a constant-power response, i.e. current draw decreases as supply voltage increases), so damping is of critical importance, as well as to deal with inrush and outside interference.
